# Resizing window and elements in JMeter on Windows 11

Tags: windows, jmeter, size

I have a problem with JMeter on Windows 11 system. When I run JMeter my elements are too small. I used "Zoom in" and my elments looks better, but I still have a problem with data in tables. Each value is truncated.  [image: How it looks]

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's connected with Windows 11, more like you have a high resolution screen and you're running JMeter on a pretty old Java which know nothing about 4k/8k screens.

Check out [JMeter and a HiDPI screen](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#hidpi) chapter of JMeter user manual for more details.

If you want to play with `sun.java2d.uiScale` property - it goes to *system.properties* file

Other mentioned properties like `jmeter.hidpi.mode`, `jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor` and so on should go to *user.properties* file

You can also try increasing the font size like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.laf=CrossPlatform "-Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=Comic Sans MS-40"
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)